# Creating additional column which contain word from other column which contain 6 letters

Tags: r

I want to create new column in R and extract informations from other column, which have 6 letters and also start sentence in row.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nS6X.jpg)

Do you have a idea, how should I do this?

Thank you for any information.

I tried use seperate function, but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello ! Please try to be more specific and read about how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using strsplit and sapply functions:

```
Seqofviruses$ID <- sapply(strsplit(Seqofviruses$seq.name," "), `[`, 1)
Seqofviruses$Definition <- sapply(strsplit(Seqofviruses$seq.name," "), `[`, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try alternatively the `substr` function as below

```r
Seqofviruses2 <- Seqofviruses %>% mutate(id=substr(seq.name,1,8), desc=substr(seq.name,9))
```